# Running two Symfony commands at the same time

Tags: symfony

I have two separate console commands within Symfony that are both run as cron jobs. When these commands happen to run at the same time, however, they both want to clear / update the dev cache and this results in one command or the other failing with a PHP fatal error "Cannot redeclare class etc etc etc".

Apart from making sure these two commands run at different times and each clears the dev cache before they run, is there any way to prevent conflicts like this in Symfony console commands?

FWIW, we have tried forcing the environment to prod, but it still seems to want to use the dev cache (so this may end up being a different question altogether):

```
$ sudo php /var/www/prod/app/console console-command --env=prod orgs --report --do-sync --welcome
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler in /var/www/prod/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 3704
```

Edit: it turns out that some of our code was explicitly defining the dev environment, totally ignoring the CLI options. Apologies.

Comment: Could you not separate the command with & ? for example app/console router:debug & app/console router:debug

Comment: In theory we could: the problem, really, is that they are unrelated commands that just both happen to be run through the Symfony console, sometimes at the same time but other times not...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using something like a Makefile

> both:     make command-one    make command-two
>
> command-one:
>       app/console foo
>
> command-two:
>       app/console bar

Then to run you could do

> make both

or

> make command-one

or

> make command-two